# pre-configure assets with robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing

In my android app I am using a configuration file for stuff like server address and some other data.
I am using Robolectric (3.0-rc) for unit-testing, with Android-Studio.
The runner is RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class

In my tests I want to edit the server url to point to a mock url, I am doing so before Robolectric.buildActivity().
Looks like somewhere, before the asset file was edited it was loaded and the test uses old data...

Where does Robolectric loads the assets?
Is there a way to reload?

Comment: how do you edit it before test? you can use BuildConfig (exmple http://toastdroid.com/2014/03/28/customizing-your-build-with-gradle/) and override values for test there

Comment: Please show some code to illustrate the problem and what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @Eugen Martynov, I've set the BuildConfig in the test module to use test assets